# connection issues between apacheds and tomcat docker containers

Tags: java, tomcat, docker, containers, apacheds

Our java web application running in tomcat container needs connection with apacheds container on port 10389 which has error as depicted in below screenshots. Tomcat container is running on 8080 and apacheds on 10389

[This is the apacheds container where we tried connecting to tomcat port 8080 which is expose in running tomcat container which worked fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkkwa.png)

[This is the tomcat container where we tried connecting to apacheds port 10389 which is expose in running apacheds container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUepS.png)

Comment: The images both appear to be the same to me. Can you also provide relevant commands you are using to start the containers and the images or `Dockerfiles` used to build them?

Comment: Yeah both images are same but now i have uploaded the correct image plz check it again

Answer (score 0):

There was problem with ldap server ip address in our webapp. After changing that it is working.